# Dynamically set tablelayout column to 2

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I need to set the table column to 2 dynamically. It only shows 1 column when I run it. I tried table.column = 2 but it does not work.

```
    table = new TableLayout(this);

    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
        row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
            row.addView(img);

        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `TableRow`'s LayoutParams. Try that. I would suggest you to use `LayoutInflater` to inflate your `TableRow`([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183968/how-to-add-rows-dynamically-into-table-layout)) from a layout xml  file and all it. If this also is giving an Error or Exception, Please post your Log.
Also, please do research before posting a question here.