# How can I add specific number of rows in a table based on the main spinner selection (in top)?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, rows, android-tablelayout

The spinner at the top specifies the number of family members you have.

If 3 is selected then 3 rows should be created with text fields, number field, spinner all at once.

This is a screenshot of my app:

[image: screenshot]

**activity_main3**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.technet_pc2.myapplication.MainActivity3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Family members"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Sr No."
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:ems="2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:ems="7"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Age"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:ems="3"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Sex"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:ems="2"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Relation"
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:ems="4"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="2"
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_column="4" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView12"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity3.java**

```java
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button b1;
    TableLayout t1;
    Spinner sp;
    ArrayAdapter ad;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

     /*  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(MainActivity3.this);
                //add Layouts to your new row
                TextView txt = new TextView(MainActivity3.this);
                txt.setText("1");
                row.addView(txt);
                //add your new row to the TableLayout:
                TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
                t1.addView(row);
            }
        });*/

        t1 = (TableLayout)MainActivity3.this.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);

        ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ad.add("Select");
        ad.add("1");
        ad.add("2");
        sp.setAdapter(ad);



           if (sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select")) {

        }
        else if (sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1")) {
            // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
           TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity3.this).inflate(R.layout.attrib_row, null);
               ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView19)).getText();
               t1.addView(row);





        }



    }
}
```

**attrib_row.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="2"
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_column="4" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recyclerview with recycler item as this:

[image]

and then in OnitemClickListner of spinner you just need to update the count in the adapter or add the item to `arraylist<CustomObject>` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

You can updated serial number as position+1 in the adapter

Comment: i tried that but how can  i write " if 1 is selected { //code// } "

Comment: you have to store the numbers in an integer array like int[] number and then you have to set onItemselectedlistner to spinner and in that you will get position and using that position you can get the number from int array and then you can use switch case or simply use if else if!

Comment: okay i tried this by else if but the the table is not updating, i think i havent set position , how to do that?

Comment: shared. i also shared attrib_row.xml i want to add rows from that layout to the activity

Comment: give your email i will share the entire solution with you!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the row dynamically and not put them statically in the layout. To achieve this, you need to extract the dynamic row (the one with the `EditText` views) to another xml and once the selector selects the number of entries, inflate the right number of rows and add them to the table.

I suggest you have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183968/how-to-add-rows-dynamically-into-table-layout) and make the proper adaptations. Don't forget to give unique ids to each of the rows as you will be collecting the data or alternately use a the ViewHolder pattern to hold and handle each row and its data.

Comment: i still dont understand how they are adding the rows, on button click or drop down?