# Data from firebase into table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created listview, which contains data from firebase. Now, I want to add this data into table, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Highscore");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Score score = postSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
                areas.add(score.getName()+" "+score.getLevel()+" "+score.getScore());
            }
            ListView highScoreSpin = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HighscoreActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, areas);
            areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            highScoreSpin.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `score.getName()`, `score.getLevel()` and `score.getScore()` you can easely add it into a `TableView`. Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183968/how-to-add-rows-dynamically-into-table-layout) to learn how it can be done.

Remember to put this lines of code outside the `onDataChange()` method.

```
ListView highScoreSpin = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HighscoreActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, areas);
areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
highScoreSpin.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
```

Hope it helps.