# Adding multiple views to a LinearLayout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem adding my TableLayout to a parent LinearLayout.
Only the first view is added to the LinearLayout.
I want to create as many TableLayouts as the response.length() is and then add them to the parent LinearLayout.

Here's the Java code:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pendingReservations);
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); ++i) {       
    final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.confirm_reservation_view,null);
    //set the TableLayout content
    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

XML codes for the layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewConfirmRes"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.konrad.rezerwacje1.ConfirmReservation">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/pendingReservations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/confirmReservationTableLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1">


    <!-- TableLayout content -->

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I already solved the issue, it was wrong orientation of my linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `TableRow` inside `TableLayout` instead of multiple `TableLayout`?

Refer to [How to add rows dynamically into table layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183968/how-to-add-rows-dynamically-into-table-layout)